# Ayuda error en codigo y obtener posicion de un array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, array

estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica el cual las canciones estan todas en una carperta, toda la lista de las canciones las obtengo con php.

Codigo:

```
<?php          
function getCanciones(){
        $directorio = opendir("../sonidos/");
        $lista='';

        while($cancion=readdir($directorio)){
                if($cancion != '.' && $cancion != '..'){
                $lista .= "<li class='cargar' id='$cancion'> $cancion</li>";
               }
        }
return $lista;
}
echo getCanciones();
?>
```

Tengo un ajax  que basicamente es para carga la lista en el html, ya le explico porque lo tengo de esta forma.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/cargar_lista.php'
    })
        .done(function (listas_rep) {
            $('#playlist').html(listas_rep)
        })
        .fail(function () {
            alert('Hubo un error al cargar las listas_rep')
        })
})
```

Y este es mi html, mostrare solo la parte donde carga la lista que se obtiene con php, añadiendo el `<li>`.

```
<div id="caja-lista">
   <ul id="playlist">                
   <ul>
</div>
```

Y ahora tengo un js el cual lo estoy trabajando con jquery donde estan todas las funciones y demas, quiero hacer un boton de next y back para las canciones pero necesito obtener la posicion de la cancion que se encuentra reproduciéndose actualmente ya que en mi codigo siempre me toma la cancion que selecciono como la ultima (hago prueba con 11 canciones).

Tengo dos formas de reproducion inicial, selecionando una cancion de la lista que se muestra o dando simplemente play que esta iniciara por la primera.

(leer los comentarios del codigo)
Codigo de seleccion de cancion cualquiera

```
    for (var i = 0; i < elementlista.length; i++) {


            elementlista[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                var cancion = this.getAttribute("id");
                audio.src = "sonidos/" + cancion;
                reproducir();
                primeraVez = true;
                document.getElementById("nombrecan").innerHTML = "<p> Reproduciendo: " + cancion + "</p>";
                console.log(cancion + ", elemento lista:" + elementlista[i] + ", Posicion:" + i);//Imprimo esto para darme cuenta la posicion de la cancion y es donde noto que siempre me dan 11 que seria el tamaño de la lista, o sea la cancion que seleccione siempre me la posiciona de ultimo
            }, false);

        }
```

Ahora si quiero solo darle play para que empieze por la primera, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
btplay.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (primeraVez == false) {

            var cancion = elementlista[0].getAttribute("id");
            audio.src = "sonidos/" + cancion;
            audio.play();
            primeraVez = true;
            btplay.src = "img/icon-pause.png";
            document.getElementById("nombrecan").innerHTML = "<p> Reproduciendo: " + cancion + "</p>";
            console.log(cancion + ", elemento lista:" + elementlista[0] + ", Posicion:");
        } else if (sonando === false) {
            reproducir();
        } else {
            pausar();
        }

    }, false);
```

Este bien pero cuando quiero darle en el boton siguiente me dice que no se puede porque segun se encontraba en la posicion.

Codigo para darle siguiente a la cancion:

```
btnNext.addEventListener('click', function () {
        i++;
        if (i >= 0) {
            var cancion = elementlista[i].getAttribute("id");
            audio.src = "sonidos/" + cancion;
            reproducir();
            primeraVez = true;
            document.getElementById("nombrecan").innerHTML = "<p> Reproduciendo: " + cancion + "</p>";
            console.log(cancion + ", elemento lista:" + elementlista[i] + ", Posicion:" + i);

        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
    }, false);
```

Si coloco `i--` me funciona pero ahora si me posiciona en la ultima cancion y anda para atras, pero por ejemplo si selecciono una cancion que se encuentra en la mitad digamos posicion 6 al darle con el  `i--` vuelve a la ultima y empieza 11, 10, 9 y asi.

Yo necesito saber la posicion verdadera y asi ya me funcionaria todo, no se que esta pasando si alguien tiene la solucion se lo agradeceria muchismo, no siendo mas muchas gracias y espero y me ayuden.

Answer (score 1):

Estás repitiendo código al hacer clic en un elemento de la lista y en el botón play.

Hay que tener en cuenta algunas variables que van a servir para poder controlar correctamente la lista de reproducción:

```
let sonando = false, // Falso hasta que se inicie la reproducción
    actual = -1;     // Esta en lugar de contador `i` y primeraVez

let nombrecan,  // Solo para no declarar cada vez
    audio,      // Igual que el anterior
    lista;      // Nombre más corto y más claro

// Obtener el elemento donde se va a colocar información
nombrecan = $('#nombrecan');
```

Ahora los eventos click, en vez de tratar de manejar un contador, deja que la función `reproducir` controle todo, recibiendo solo el elemento que va a reproducir/pausar/reanudar:

```
// Elementos de lista
lista = $('#playlist li');
for(let item in lista) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Enviar el elemento a la función
        reproducir(this);
    });
}
// Botón play
btnplay.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Verificar si ya hay canción, si no, comenzar desde cero
    let pos = (actual == -1) ? 0 : actual;
    // Enviar elemento por su posición en la lista
    reproducir(lista[pos]);
});
```

Como comenté arriba, deja que una sola función controle todo el funcionamiento, así evitas duplicar código:

```
function reproducir(item) {
    // Obtener posición del elemento recibido
    let cual = $(item).parent().children().index(item);
    // Si la posición no es igual al del elemento en reproducción
    if(cual != actual) {
        // Se cambió de canción, hay que actualizar algunas cosas
        let cancion = item.getAttribute('id');
        audio.src = 'sonidos/' + cancion;
        audio.play();
            btplay.src = "img/icon-pause.png";
        nombrecan.innerHTML = `<p>Reproduciendo ${cancion}</p>`;
        console.log(`Canción: ${cancion} - Elemento de lista: ${actual}`);

        // Actualizar elemento actual, para evitar entrar aquí
        // si se selecciona otra vez la misma canción
        actual = cual;
        // Para controlar pausa o reanudar
        sonando = true;
    } else if(sonando) {
        // Es la misma canción y está sonando... pausar!
        audio.pause();
        sonando = false;
        // Se debería cambiar la imagen play/pause?
    } else {
        // Es la misma canción, no está sonando... reanudar!
        audio.play();
        sonando = true;
        // Se debería cambiar la imagen play/pause?
    }
    // Anterior / siguiente?
    if(actual > 0) {
        // No se está reproduciendo la primera canción
        // Puedes habilitar el botón Anterior
    }
    if(actual < lista.length - 1) {
        // No se está reproduciendo la última canción
        // Puedes habilitar el botón Siguiente
    }
}
```

Ahora solo falta agregar los eventos para botones anterior y siguiente. No es tan complicado, de hecho, es muy parecido a lo que se hace con el botón play, pero ambos botones llamarán a una misma función y, de acuerdo al parámetro enviado, el reproductor retrocede o avanza en la lista de canciones:

```
// Función para anterior o siguiente
function prevNext(accion) {
    // Obtener el elemento de acuerdo a la acción y posición actual
    // prev, entonces -1    next, entonces + 1
    item = (accion == 'prev') ? lista[actual - 1] : lista[actual + 1];
    reproducir(item);
}

btnPrev.addEventListener('click', function() {
    prevNext('prev');
});

btnNext.addEventListener('click', function() {
    prevNext('next');
});
```